# How do I open a file for writing in C winApi?

Tags: c, file, winapi

If i want to create a new file, I simply do something like:

```
HANDLE hFile;
hFile = CreateFileW(L"D:\\winApiFiles\\file1.txt",
        GENERIC_WRITE,
        0,
        NULL,
        CREATE_NEW,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        NULL);
```

and then use WriteFile.

But if the file already exists, WriteFile fails.
I want to make my program open the existing file for writing, if CreateFileW fails due to the file existing already. How do I make that?

Comment: From [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew): `CREATE_NEW` -- "Creates a new file, only if it does not already exist. If the specified file exists, the function fails..." (it probably took less time to google `CreateFileW` and look that up, than it took you to write the question.)

Comment: From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew): *"`OPEN_ALWAYS` Opens a file, **always**."*

Comment: "*But if the file already exists, WriteFile fails.*" - don't you mean `CreateFileW()` fails?

Answer (score 1):

Per the [`CreateFileW()` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew):

> | Value | Meaning |
> | --- | --- |
> | CREATE_NEW 1 | Creates a new file, **only if it does not already exist**. **If the specified file exists, the function fails and the last-error code is set to ERROR_FILE_EXISTS (80).** If the specified file does not exist and is a valid path to a writable location, a new file is created. |

If you want to *overwrite* an existing file, and *create* a new file if it doesn't exist, use `CREATE_ALWAYS` instead:

| Value | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| CREATE_ALWAYS 2 | Creates a new file, always. If the specified file exists and is writable, the function overwrites the file, the function succeeds, and last-error code is set to ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS (183). If the specified file does not exist and is a valid path, a new file is created, the function succeeds, and the last-error code is set to zero. |

If you want to *append* to an existing file, and *create* a new file if it doesn't exist, then use `OPEN_ALWAYS` instead (and then seek the file to the end using `SetFilePointer/Ex()` after opening it, if `GetLastError()` returns `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS`):

| Value | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| OPEN_ALWAYS 4 | Opens a file, always. If the specified file exists, the function succeeds and the last-error code is set to ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS (183). If the specified file does not exist and is a valid path to a writable location, the function creates a file and the last-error code is set to zero. |